# Reorder selective columns from a large dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a large pandas dataframe - lets say 150 columns, that can even grow each time the code runs. What I am looking for is how can I bring few selected columns to the front of the dataframe(which I know will always be there).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Index [`intersection`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.intersection.html)/[`union`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.union.html):

```
cols = ['E', 'A', 'B']

out = df[pd.Index(cols).intersection(df.columns).union(df.columns, sort=False)]
```

If you are sure that `cols` only contains valid columns:

```
out = df[pd.Index(cols).union(df.columns, sort=False)]
```

Output:

```
   E  A  B  C  D  F  G  H
0  4  0  1  2  3  5  6  7
```

Used input:

```
   A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H
0  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
```

Alternative if you want to bring the columns in the front but keep their relative original order:

```
out = df.sort_index(axis=1, key=lambda x: x.isin(cols), ascending=False)
```

Output:

```
   A  B  E  C  D  F  G  H
0  0  1  4  2  3  5  6  7
```